# Mysterious crash report appeared in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, debugging, google-play

I have published an app on Google Play Store and sometime a wild crash report appear on my Google Play Developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3535)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3575)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2817)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1528)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6316)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4191)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3509)
```

It just doesn't show anything about the code i wrote... therefore i have NO IDEA about how to tackle this problem.

How should i behave when i come across a report like this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure there's no other Caused by down under?

Comment: is there is no other caused by then try using change version of application

Comment: @eduyayo unfortunately no... that's the entire stack data shown in console